# How to add a file to upload in message flow of Mule ESB?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mule, mule-studio

This is my Controller use SpringMVC, it has 2 params is "file" and "fileDesc":

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadfiles", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String createResource(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files, @RequestParam("fileDesc") String fileDesc, Locale locale)
        throws IOException, ServiceProcessException {...}
```

And this is my design in Mule:

[image]

I don't know how to get files to get value in controller because data I send to Mule then point to Controler in runtime.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? It seems you are hitting ```/resourcefiles``` but the actual path is ```/uploadfiles```. What would a successful request to that path look like?

Comment: oh sorry for that, I changed path to /uploadfiles in Controller. Problem is I dont know how to add a file to mule like the tool Postman, and get value that file into Controller.
Thank for your help !

Comment: Could you share what the Postman request looks like? That way be can see how to replicate that with Mule.

Answer (score 0):

A similar use case has been discussed [here](http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/multipart-file-upload-missing-filename).

HTH.